# Songs package with smaller margins

Tags: memoir, songs

I am trying to typeset a songbook using the `songs` package. The code is available below. The problem is that whenever I change the values of `\setlrmarginsandblock` and `\setulmarginsandblock`, nothing appears to happen with the layout at all. The current layout of the first part of the song below is

[image]

(Don't mind that the number of the song is 3, I removed some other songs from the example code below.)

There is far too much space both above, but especially below the song. This takes up a lot of space, making the songbook unnecessarily long. How can I make the margins smaller?

```
\documentclass[a5paper,14pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\renewcommand{\danishhyphenmins}{22}

\pagestyle{empty}

\setlrmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{*}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.8cm}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{0cm}{0cm}
\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]
%\usepackage[chorded]{songs}

\usepackage[lyric]{songs}
\setlength\baselineadj{-\baselineskip}

\usepackage{graphicx,comment,amssymb,amstext,amsthm,geometry,array,xspace,xkeyval,xfrac,bm,mathtools,listings, wasysym}
\newindex{myindex}{myindex}
\spenalty=0
\songcolumns{1}
\setlength{\sbarheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\cbarwidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chorusfont}{\itshape}
%\versesep=12pt plus 2pt minus 6pt
%\versesep=12pt plus 2pt minus 8pt
%\versesep=8pt plus 2pt minus 6pt
\versesep=12pt plus 2pt minus 8pt
%\versesep=8pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
\chordson

\begin{document}
\showindex{Indhold}{myindex}
    \begin{songs}{myindex}
        \beginsong{Et barn er født i Bethlehem}[by={N. F. S. Grundtvig, \melody{} A. P. Berggreen}]
        \beginverse
        Et barn er født i Bethlehem,
        thi glæder sig Jerusalem.
        \endverse
        \beginverse
        En fattig jomfru sad i løn,
        og fødte himlens kongesøn.
        \endverse
        \beginverse         
        Han lagdes i et krybberum,
        Guds engle sang med fryd derom.
        \endverse
        \beginverse
        Og østens vise ofred der,
        Guld, røgelse og myrra skær.
        \endverse
        \beginverse 
        Forvunden er nu al vor nød,
        os er i dag en frelser fød.
        \endverse
        \beginverse 
        Guds kære børn vi blev påny,
        skal holde jul i himmelby.
        \endverse
        \beginverse 
        På stjernetæpper lyse blå,
        skal glade vi til kirke gå.
        \endverse
        \beginverse
        Guds engle der os lære brat,
        at synge, som de sang i nat.
        \endverse
        \beginverse
        Da vorde engle vi som de,
        Guds milde ansigt skal vi se.
        \endverse
        \beginverse
        Ham være pris til evig tid,
        for frelser bold og broder blid!
        \endverse
    \endsong
        \end{songs}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set up the page layout correctly, but then you load the `geometry` package, which makes a new page layout based purely on the paper size `a5paper`.  Removing the `geometry` package fixes the problem.  In fact, I could not see where any of the packages in that used package statement were used in the example, so I have removed them all below:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,14pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\renewcommand{\danishhyphenmins}{22}

\pagestyle{empty}

\setlrmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{*}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.8cm}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{0cm}{0cm}
\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]
%\usepackage[chorded]{songs}

\usepackage[lyric]{songs}
\setlength\baselineadj{-\baselineskip}

\newindex{myindex}{myindex}
\spenalty=0
\songcolumns{1}
\setlength{\sbarheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\cbarwidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chorusfont}{\itshape}
\versesep=12pt plus 2pt minus 8pt
\chordson

\begin{document}
\showindex{Indhold}{myindex}
    \begin{songs}{myindex}
        \beginsong{Et barn er født i Bethlehem}[by={N. F. S. Grundtvig, Melody: A. P. Berggreen}]
        \beginverse
        Et barn er født i Bethlehem,
        thi glæder sig Jerusalem.
        \endverse
        \beginverse
        En fattig jomfru sad i løn,
        og fødte himlens kongesøn.
        \endverse
        \beginverse         
        Han lagdes i et krybberum,
        Guds engle sang med fryd derom.
        \endverse
        \beginverse
        Og østens vise ofred der,
        Guld, røgelse og myrra skær.
        \endverse
        \beginverse 
        Forvunden er nu al vor nød,
        os er i dag en frelser fød.
        \endverse
        \beginverse 
        Guds kære børn vi blev påny,
        skal holde jul i himmelby.
        \endverse
        \beginverse 
        På stjernetæpper lyse blå,
        skal glade vi til kirke gå.
        \endverse
        \beginverse
        Guds engle der os lære brat,
        at synge, som de sang i nat.
        \endverse
        \beginverse
        Da vorde engle vi som de,
        Guds milde ansigt skal vi se.
        \endverse
        \beginverse
        Ham være pris til evig tid,
        for frelser bold og broder blid!
        \endverse
    \endsong
        \end{songs}

\end{document}
```

My version of the `songs` package does not define `\melody` command, so I replaced it by some text.

Breaks between songs are controlled by the `\songpos` macro.  Default value of `3` avoids breaks within songs at much as possible.  `\songpos{0}` allows many different breaks.

Comment: Well, some commands, like `\melody`, where defined by myself, but were removed from the instructive example. I accidentally left traces of it behind. But thanks for the answer! BTW, Andrew, thank you for an interesting geometry course at AU. :-)

Comment: Velbekomme!....